# Particle system prefab not instantiated

Tags: unity, c#, particles, instancing

I am trying to instantiate my fire particle system during runtime like this:

```
GameObject fire, firePrefab;

void Start()
{
    ...
    firePrefab = Resources.Load("FirePrefab") as GameObject;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.V))
   {
       fire = Instantiate(firePrefab, transform.GetChild(3).position, transform.GetChild(3).rotation);
       Destroy(fire, 5.0f);
   }
}
```

My FirePrefab is just a regular particle system, and the model the above script is attached to looks like this:

> Model
>
> > Default
> >
> > Camera
> >
> > DroneFire

However, my fire prefab isn't instantiated anywhere when I run the game.

Comment: Any errors? Did you check if fireprefab is actually loaded and not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetChild` is zero-based. to get the first object, "Default",  you would call `GetChild(0)`. In your case, to get "DroneFire", you should call `GetChild(2)`, *not* `GetChild(3)` which will throw an exception before the instantiation can occur, because no such child exists. This exception should be fairly obvious in the console output. I would recommend looking in the console regularly when things don't work to find where things are failing.

```
fire = Instantiate(firePrefab, transform.GetChild(2).position, transform.GetChild(2).rotation)
```

As a side note, polling for input should generally not be done in `FixedUpdate`. Change to `Update` instead.